# How to select a performance counter with Get-Counter with * in name

Tags: powershell, performancecounter

When I try to select a counter of which I know the name and the fact that is exists, like for example `Get-Counter -ListSet '\ProcessorPerformance(*)\frequency' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Counter`, I get the error that:

> Get-Counter : Cannot find any performance counter sets on the
>   localhost computer that match the following:
>   \ProcessorPerformance(*)\frequency. At line:1 char:1

How can I get a counter when I know the full name or path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you can find help on the [scripting guy site](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/07/28/use-performance-counter-sets-and-powershell-to-ease-baselining.aspx) :

```
(Get-Counter -ListSet 'processor information').paths  | get-counter
```

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing sets and counters.  The *counter* `'Processor Frequency'` is contained within the *set* named `'Processor Information'`.  Your example is asking for a *set* named `'\ProcessorPerformance(*)\frequency'`, which does not exist.

A brief example:

```
# Get the set for Processor Information.
$set = Get-Counter -ListSet 'Processor Information'
# List available counters in set.
$set.Counter

# Alternatively, get just the specific counter.
Get-Counter -Counter '\Processor Information(*)\Processor Frequency'
```

Comment: `Get-Counter -Counter '\Processor Performance(*)\Processor Frequency'` does not work

Comment: @user2609980 Really sorry about that, I'd copied from your question the 'processorperformance' bit. The set name is 'Processor Information'.  I've tested the above examples and [produced a screenshot to verify](http://imgur.com/eamHMLN).

Comment: Thanks! I've got it working now. Good devloper took a look and used .net classes in powershell!